permutation of the determinant according to the groups $S_{n1}$ and $S_{n2}$?
Reading about alternating linear n maps, I found this alternative definition of a determinant, based on its permutation expression (which iteratively sums the product of all the permutations that can be made with the entries of a matrix).
note: by "inversion" I mean the change of order in the terms, perhaps the translation is not clear regarding this word.
I can see that they divide the permutations into $2$ groups:
$S_{n1}$ permutations such that $p(i) p(j)$ is inversion.
$S_{n2}$ permutations such that $p(i) p(j)$ is not an inversion.
What I understand by inversion is:
$x_1 x_2 x_3$ (main permutation (without inversions))
$x_2 x_3 x_1$ (permutation with two inversions ($x_3 x_1,x_2 x_1$))
And what I understand by transposition is:
As i read, in several related properties, the transposition is a permutation that exchanges two of the indices, leaving the rest fixed (for a transposition (i j) it exchanges i with j and leaves the other elements fixed). In turn, every k-cycle (set of permutations whose initial and final element are the same, with k number of elements) is a composition of k-1 transpositions, the transposition being a type of cycle with 2 inverted elements. I say this because, Every permutation $σ∈S_{n}$ is a composition of transpositions, decomposing the permutations into disjoint cycles, and then decomposing each cycle into transpositions, and a permutation can well be called a transposition.
$\color{red}{EXPRESSION}$ $\color{red}{1.}$
$$\sum_{ p \in S_{n}}\sigma(p)a_{1p(1)}...\lambda a_{ip(i)}...a_{np(n)}+\sigma(\bar{q})a_{1\bar{q}(1)}...\lambda a_{i\bar{q}(i)}...a_{n\bar{q}(n)}=0$$
Now, it says in the book that $q$ is a transposition with respect to each permutation $p$, that is, $q=p.t$, whose sign will be opposite to the permutation in question, resulting in: $∀ p \in S_{n1}$, $∃q \in S_{n2}$ $|$ $p=q.t$, from which they describe to me that it arises, $p.t=(q.t).t=p.t=\bar q$, then $\bar q =q=p.t$ (I find it confusing that they present $q$ and $\bar q$  as the same, but i think the point is facilitate $\color{red}{EXPRESSION}$ $\color{red}{1.}$ from $p∈S_{n}$ as seen).
that contains for p (I suppose that it takes as main permutations all those that its set includes since it is assumed that they are not in inversion), their respective transposed versions q towards the particular permutation that, since there are 2 equal rows or columns in the matrix, ends up canceling the addition operation present in the $\color{red}{EXPRESSION} \color{red}{1.}$ (that each iteration of the summation returns a $0$), given the transposition of a permutation it alters the order of the entries, but not their value (the product is commutative) and, the sign changes , which will end up giving $0$.
$\color{red}{Q1.}$ Is my reasoning about the function of $\bar q$ so far correct?
$\color{red}{EXPRESSION}$ $\color{red}{2}$ appears in the book but I see $\color{red}{EXPRESSION}$ $\color{red}{3}$ presented below as more logical.
$\color{red}{EXPRESSION}$ $\color{red}{2:}$ $$\sum_{p\in S_{n}}\sigma(p)a_{1p(1)}...\lambda a_{ip(i)}...a_{np(n)}=\sum_{p\in S_{1}}\sigma(p)a_{1p(1)}...\lambda a_{ip(i)}...a_{np(n)}+\sum_{q\in S_{n}}\sigma(q)a_{1q(1)}...\lambda a_{iq(i)}...a_{nq(n)}$$
$\color{red}{EXPRESSION}$ $\color{red}{3:}$ $$\sum_{p\in S_{n}}\sigma(p)a_{1p(1)}...\lambda a_{ip(i)}...a_{np(n)}=\sum_{p\in S_{1}}\sigma(p)a_{1p(1)}...\lambda a_{ip(i)}...a_{np(n)}+\sum_{q\in S_{2}}\sigma(q)a_{1q(1)}...\lambda a_{iq(i)}...a_{nq(n)}$$
Which would then be transformed into:
$$\sum_{p \in S_{n}}\sigma(p)a_{1p(1)}...\lambda a_{ip(i)}...a_{np(n)}+\sigma(\bar{q})a_{1\bar{q}(1)}...\lambda a_{i\bar{q}(i)}...a_{n\bar{q}(n)}=0$$
I understand, first of all, that an alternate application is one that returns a $0$ when the matrix on which it acts has two or more equal rows or columns.
The expression seems wrong to me because I see no way in which, assuming that transposing the entire set of permutations $S_{n}$ as suggested, would yield the final result that the proof of alternation requires since, in any case, a part of $S_{n}$ would be canceled with $S_{1}$, leaving other values intact, I see it as more logical that the second summation is with respect to $S_{2}$ since that is how I see that the result would lead to the cancellation of values that I believe the demonstration seeks, for the case in which an alternate application is applied to a matrix with equal rows or columns.
$\color{red}{Q2.}$ Is the expression that comes out of the book ($\color{red}{EXPRESSION}$ $\color{red}{2}$) and that is doubtful to me correct? Or is my interpretation ($\color{red}{EXPRESSION}$ $\color{red}{3}$)?
